# Tool to extract English nouns/names from a text

Tags: python

I need a tool or program to separate English nouns and names from a text like:

> I like apples, I live in NewYork.

This would give `apples` and `NewYork`.

Is there a library or tool that can do this or a big list of all words that are not nouns/names (in English)?

Comment: Should it recognize "Apples" or "apples"? And "NewYork" or "New York"?

Comment: What about "New York is the big apple"?  ;-)

Comment: Capital letters dont matter. And probaly New is reconize as adjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [spacy](https://spacy.io/). It's based on ML and NLP, and is trained to do stuff like finding nouns, which includes names (though it does more too, but since that's what you're looking for, I use that as an example).

The [docs](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features) contains some examples on finding nouns, so it should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but in my necessity i make my own: https://github.com/vncsms/GetNouns . It´s not 100% but works fine by me.